# Description for Explainer, Refiner, Illuminator is unclear

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, badge-description, edit-and-answer-badges

The text on the badge description page reads as follows:

> Edited X questions within 12 hours of posting a positive-scoring answer.

I was not the only one who thought this meant you edited *any* question after posting a positive-scoring answer.  This left me puzzled by the random combination of requirements for a badge, but then someone directed me to the meta post suggesting the badge, after which I understood.

But it could use some clarification, perhaps:

> Edited X questions within 12 hours of posting a positive-scoring answer to those questions.

Comment: Haha, even if regarding the same question, the combination between editing and answering is still random anyway. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator?rq=1) for the rationale of why it isn't random.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, it was just a small joke. I've read that other thread, but to me it's still a rather random connection (or rather a special version of the already existing edit badges). But nevermind.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, that was confusing. Changed:

> [image: Edited and answered X question(s) (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)]

Comment: I like description suggested by OP more than this.

Comment: It flows better, but... I'm not interested in doing this again in a day when someone else gets confused because they accidentally a word.

Comment: I find that explanation really confusing. For me, it reads as if the requirements for Refiner are: "Within 12 hours, do 50 times: 'Edit question and provide answer with positive score'".

Comment: This: *"Edited and answered 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours...)* taken literally would mean, e.g., between lunch and midnight you answered (score >0) and edited 50 questions.  But clearly that is not what the badge is for -- if it is you deserve a platinum badge with rubies, and a new car.

Comment: @goldilocks I had the same misreading. I think it shoudl say "Edit and answer 50 question (both action for the same question within 12 hours)"