# What is the Refiner badge really for?

Tags: support, badge-description, edit-and-answer-badges

The blurb for Refiner says,

> Edited and answered 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

which dates back [to here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240300/212479).

Breaking this down, we have "edited and answered 50 questions".  That's five zero, fifty.  "Edited and answered" -> it's ambiguous whether that means you edited 50 questions and also answered them, or whether you edited 50 questions and answered 50 questions which may or may not be the same.  But the number is still fifty.

> **both actions within 12 hours**

That is stupendous.  And all you get is a silver badge?  Of course, if there is no further qualification, you just have to edit and answer 4 questions per hour.  Okay, fair enough, but

> **answer score > 0**

That's really impressive.  50 questions answered in 12 hours, and all of them upvoted.  And since badges are per site, that's on one exchange.

Surely this person deserves a new car...unless I'm somehow misreading this by taking it at face value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The

> both actions within 12 hours

part refers to the fact that the editing of the question and posting the answer must take place within 12 hours. That action (on a single question, and if the answer has a positive score – note that the positive score may come later than 12 hours) will give you the bronze [Explainer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer) badge.

The *Refiner* badge just requires you to do that on 50 different questions, but there's no time limit between the first and the last question. It can take years to get one.

Comment: Refiner is reasonably okay to get - just don't mention Illuminator - that's the real challenge... :p

Comment: Okay I can see it that way >_>

Comment: I understand your confusion, but it's hard to write concise badge descriptions without a little ambiguity.

Comment: Here is an easier way to get these badges: For each question you answer, you also edit the question as well.

I also make downvotes with comment if the question is very badly formatted or missing important information, and then if the asker answers the comment I will work hard to answer it.