# Explainer badge understanding

Tags: discussion, badges

I was recently awarded the [Explainer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer). I tried searching for more information on this badge, but I still do not understand why I have been awarded this badge? Can someone explain how I received this badge?

On the badge page, it says this for the Explainer badge:

> Edited and answered 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer
>   score > 0).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You answered a question. Your score on your answer is greater than 1. *(So this means you have 1 upvote and 0 downvotes or better. Or you could have 21 upvotes and 20 downvotes.)* Just need to see the number 1 or higher for your score.

You need to have edited the question that you answered either within 12 hours before you posted your answer or edited it within 12 hours after you posted your answer.

For example, I just left you this answer, now I will go edit your question to improve it. (*note: you should only make edits when you can actually improve something on the question*)

OK, I edited your question. So 12 hours from now, If my answer has a score of 1 or better, I will get 1 credit for the Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator badge.

---

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228743/illuminator-badge-progress) by Jon / Martijn which will show you the count you have for these three badges. Just enter your userId (*yours is 1997103 on Stack Overflow*) in the input and click run.

Here is a modified [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229431/illuminator-badge-progress-test-for-showing-the-question-link-where-earned-credi) of the above one, which will give you a link to those questions of which you answered and edited to earn credit towards those badges.

Answer (score 9):

[Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240302/214632) gives the details for this badge (and the associated silver and gold badges). To wit:

> If you post an answer and edit the question within 12 hours of each other (it doesn't matter which happens first) and:
>
> - you did not post the question;
> - neither the question nor the answer are deleted;
> - the question is not closed;
> - the answer has a positive score; and
> - the edit to the question changes either the body or the title (or both)
>
> then those actions make you eligible for the Explainer badge.

More actions of this sort will give you the Refiner and Illuminator badges.