# Add post link to Explainer badge

Tags: feature-request, edits, badges

Is it possible to add a link to the question for which you earned the [Explainer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer?userid=295232)?

> Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0).

It's usually not too difficult to find the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277921/295232) by checking which answers you posted a few hours before the badge was awarded. However, it's possible to get an Explainer badge for a relatively old post which gets its first upvote only after a couple of days have passed.

Other editing badges with bronze, silver and/or gold variants like [Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor?userid=295232) and [Excavator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/158/excavator?userid=295232) already show the post you've earned them for.

Answer (score 1):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229431/illuminator-badge-progress-test-for-showing-the-question-link-where-earned-credi),
identified in [CRABOLO’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240339/271976#240340) to [Explainer badge understanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240339/271976),
is written to show you all the questions that count toward
your “Explainer” / “Refiner” / “Illuminator” badges.