# Can we have related questions listed for the new Explainer badge series?

Tags: feature-request, badges, edit-and-answer-badges

The new badges, [Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator), have been described in detail and apparently implemented.

My request is that we include the relevant questions that earned us this badge/these badges in list form. If not directly on the page (500 links for the gold badge might be too many), then perhaps at least a link to a page dedicated to such a list?

Comment: You can probably get the list of questions from a SEDE query.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm not really familiar with that (Data Explorer, right?), but the point of the request is that I don't have to do my own analytics to find the relevant questions.

Comment: Well in the meantime, since it could potentially take 6-8  or 42 something get implemented - you could use the data explorer.

Comment: This is not done for any other badges that are not linked to a specific post. (In fact, it should not be done for some of them, like Civic Duty.) I think it makes sense to keep it this way: there is nothing special about the first n questions you happened to edit/answer; the badge is given for the behavioral pattern, not for each of those particular edits.

Comment: @CareBear I agree there is some inconsistent behavior with badges linking questions for n-related actions. However, from the point of view of someone curious about what specific instance of an action garnered them a new badge, *as well as* a curiosity for how many total actions of this type they have performed, I think this would be useful and appreciated. At least, it would be by me.

Comment: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228743/illuminator-badge-progress?UserId=2756409) shows 9 qualifying answeredits for you as of the last SEDE update, i.e., last weekend.

Comment: @lostsock Not a dupe; that question asks what the badges *are*. This question is a *feature request* to enhance the badges' current implementation.

Answer (score 9):

I created a Data Explorer query for you: [List all answers that count for the Illuminator badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge).

It'll list all your answers that qualify, ordered by date (newest first).

The Data Explorer database is updated once a week on Sundays, so the list is perhaps a little out of date. On Stack Overflow, you have [9 qualifying answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge?UserId=2756409#resultSets), not including any new ones you posted since Sunday.

It's part of my series of queries for the new badges:

- [Top illuminators](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228741/top-illuminators) - Top Illuminator badge holders sorted by qualifying answer count
- [Illuminator badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228743/illuminator-badge-progress) - Count how many qualifying answers you have
- [Most effective Illuminators](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229980/most-effective-illuminators) - Illuminator badge holders ranked by weighted qualifying answers (count * percentage of total answers)
- [List all answers that count for the Illuminator badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge) - Date-sorted list of qualifying answers