# Why some Badges have more details than others?

Tags: support, badges

Why for some badges I can see details about the question or answer I was rewarded a badge for, and for others no?

For example, if I click *Notable question* I can see what is that question, but for *Explainer* no link to a question or answer is provided, but is surely known what questions lead to awarding the badge: *Edit and answer (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240387/can-we-have-related-questions-listed-for-the-new-explainer-badge-series.

Answer (score 4):

When you received the Notable Question badge, it is always about one question. The Explainer badge on the other hand is more complex. There is more calculation behind it before it gets awarded.

I think it will be more confusing if you get a list of all posts that contributed to an Explainer badge than it is now. You can always use SEDE to see the questions the badge was about. For most badges there is a script to calculate your progress and the details.

For example [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge) for Illuminator (the gold badge of Refiner and Explainer).