# Do self-answered questions count as progress towards the Explainer, Refiner, Illuminator badges?

Tags: support, edits, answers, badges, edit-and-answer-badges

I tend to answer my own questions if they remain unanswered for some time, and I wondered this:

If I edit my question within 12 hours before or after answering it, like I do with others' questions, will that count as progress toward the [Explainer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer), [Refiner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/247/refiner), and [Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) answer [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. [Per the requirements documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator/240302#240302):

> Edited *n* questions within 12 hours of posting an answer (that's 12 hours before *or* after answering), where:
>
> - **The question was asked by someone other than the answerer**
> - Neither the questions nor the answers are deleted
> - The questions are not closed
> - The answers score > 0
> - The question edits changed either body, titles, or both

Answer (score 4):

I picked a [self answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379879/advertisingidclient-getadvertisingidinfo-hangs-forever) on SO, seems to meet requirements.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079153/failing-tests-allowed-in-bamboo/18121275) seems to qualify too.

Looks like you don't get those badges for self-answered questions.