# Should questions without enough info, but a good + accepted answer, be deleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, moderation

Example question (paraphrasing an answer on Stack Overflow):

> My website appears upside-down. Please fix it. [LINK](http://goo.gl/KkcvTf)

Example (and, theoretically, accepted) answer:

> I see that you applied `transform: rotate(180deg);` to `body`. Just remove that line, and you'll be good.

---

My question:

How should these questions and answers be handled? On Stack Overflow, I'd start with closing the question as `Off-Topic > "why isn't this code working?"`? Other Stack Exchange sites have comparable close reasons (*[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)* has "the question is not fully defined", etc.).

Comment: Given that such as site *does* have a "why isn't this code working" (I think thats only SO), Down vote, close, delete. Does anything more need to be done?

Answer (score 2):

If it has a valuable answer, i wouldn't delete it. I would *improve* the question, so that it is also valuable.

As Tim Post [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator):

> I can't begin to count the number of times I've justified re-opening a question as a moderator by saying:
>
> > Look at the answer it got, though. This isn't something we want deleted, this is something we want fixed, because it's obviously valuable. Someone with domain knowledge can easily edit that question based on the answer it received.

This is why the Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator badges were created - to encourage people to improve the questions they answer, so that both the question and answer are good.