# What goes on behind the scenes when determining if a badge should be implemented?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request, feature-request-process

I understand you can probably just post a question and tag it as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to suggest one, but I was wondering what goes behind the scenes when determining whether or not a badge should be implemented? Are there things to keep in mind before suggesting a new badge?

Comment: It needs research like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247415/should-we-make-the-red-baron-hat-trigger-a-permanent-badge) or [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator) and you might want to go over [tag:badge-request]

Comment: Do some reading on previous requests similar or close to the one you want to suggest, chances are it's been suggested, even if in a slightly different way or name. If you are confident it would be useful and not discussed previously, then go for it. If you are unsure, then you could always post a "discussion" first and get some general feedback on what others think

Comment: Ah okay I didn't have a badge request in mind -- I just wanted to know what the process was if there was any. If either of you wants to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because your question seems to call for Stack devs/staff to inform you more about their side of things - "what goes on behind the scenes when determining if a badge should be implemented" and "what is the process of implementing badges"

Comment: Oh I based from your comment that was the "process". I guess I'll leave this question here if there is more elaboration on it then. I'll change my question to fit that because that does pique my interest :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the question asked is exactly a duplicate of mine but the answer does address my question. I can delete this question if necessary.