# foo.stackexchange.com should redirect appropriately

Tags: bug, redirection

What should happen if you type one of the following URLs into your browser?

- http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com
- http://superuser.stackexchange.com
- http://serverfault.stackexchange.com
- http://askubuntu.stackexchange.com
- http://stackapps.stackexchange.com

...because this is what you get:

[image: Sad panda]

Comment: Why should they redirect?

Comment: 'cos that panda is ugly.

Comment: Clearly they should all redirect to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas

Comment: That is offensive @MartinJames and you run the risk of being banned! :P

Comment: As far as bears go, Pandas aren't too bad, so I give them a pass.  The rest of them can go pound sand.

Comment: Good call, this is a dupe.

Comment: Wow, I'm totally nonplussed by the "No" answer on that other question, and the bizarre justification in the comments. It would be reasonable to say "This issue is tiny, and not worth the time to fix".  But to double-down and pretend that the site's behavior is already correct as-is? Very strange...

Comment: @superbatfish well, it's not declined just yet, so it might still happen. One day.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nah, just need ["6-8 years"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247415/should-we-make-the-red-baron-hat-trigger-a-permanent-badge#comment940166_247415)

Comment: @Panda heh, didn't want to discourage the OP here. :-)