# FGITW sub-problem: poor questions answered instead of edited. Motivate answer-ers to improve question first

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers

Here's the scenario:

1. Someone asks a poor question
2. A potential answer-er keen for reputation sees that the poor question has deterred any answers so far, and takes the opportunity to answer the question without competing against other fellow FGITW answer-ers. The answer-er takes the time to understand the confusing question and write a well written and correct answer.
3. the OP likes the answer, and accepts it
4. Who is motivated to improve the question now?

## The rep does not provide incentive to answer-ers to improve poor questions

The Stack Overflow help article ["How do I write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) advises that not all questions should be answered, provides a detailed list of the sorts of questions not to answer, and recommends editing a question to improve it. But, there the rep incentive says the opposite:

*Rep for fixing question:* +2 suggested edit is accepted

*Rep for correct answer:* +15 accepted answer, maybe +10 for upvote, etc.

## Correct incentives important for gamification

In response to the anticipated push-back: *"Just do the right thing and improve the question"* ... Valid objection, but surely we can do better than that? The heart of [gamification (2010 Coding Horror post about gamification's part in SO design)](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/) is to provide incentives for the sort of behavior that we want in order to make problem solving fun, and to help people work towards a goal.

## Suggestion

Withhold rep for answers on a question until the question has a vote total of zero or more. If the question has zero votes and an answer is accepted or upvoted, reward the rep. If the question is subsequently downvoted, remove that rep until it is back at zero or above. Thus, both the OP and anyone who wants to answer the question are responsible for making sure the question is up to snuff. This is consistent with [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

## Related (but different) problems

- [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) - different because that question addresses producing quality questions
- [Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system) - different because that question is about preventing poor questions in the first place, rather than improving poor questions

Comment: umm... looks like you missed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator

Comment: Yup, I missed that.

Comment: Aren't you worried that someone in it for the rep upon seeing an awful question at -1, and their 15 pts acceptance plus 10 pts for a helpful answer going uncounted, will just upvote the question?

Comment: Yup, that would also be a problem - you could get around it by excluding their vote in the total or something like that, but that's getting a bit more messy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We already have [three badges exactly for this purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator): encouraging users to edit the question before answering. Don't have data to see how successful this is, but pretty sure it's working well.

Preventing reputation is a bad idea in my opinion, and will just antagonize users, or even worse make them upvote the question even though it doesn't deserve it, just so they can get reputation.

I don't want such a feature.