# Explainer badge not awarded

Tags: support, badges, edit-and-answer-badges

I recently [answered and edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376726/how-to-detect-a-colored-rectangles-in-an-image/35376992#35376992), but didn't receive an explainer badge.
I found a couple of questions from people who appeared to have the same problem as I do, but in the end it turned out they just didn't meet all the conditions for the badge.

The time between my edit and my answer was 1-2 hours. Following all the bullet points for an explainer badge from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator/240302#240302):

> - The question was asked by someone other than the answerer

Yes, I didn't ask the question

> - Neither the questions nor the answers are deleted

Also true

> - The questions are not closed

The question is open

> - The answers score > 0

I have a score of 1

> - The question edits changed either body, titles, or both

I edited both the title and body (I *also* added two tags, but that shouldn't be an issue..)

Any ideas why I didn't get my badge? Am I just too impatient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From looking at the [timings of Explainer badge awards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) it seems like the process that awards such badges runs around every 6 hours or so.

[Wilbur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2399775/wilbur) currently has only one answer on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) so it's easy to determine why he got the badge. His badge was awarded on Feb 4 at 4:53 but his answer was Feb 3 16:40 and his edit to the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291525/merge-angular2-and-angularjs-2-0-and-angularjs-2) at Feb 3 at 17:14, there were [2 upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/316099/timeline) by midnight on Feb 3 so he has a 5 or so hour gap between eligibility and award.

That being the case your answer is simply too new to have been scanned by the awarder process. Wait a bit and you should get your badge. And in fact [you now have the Explainer badge.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer?userid=4298200)