# Why am I not receiving the "explainer" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I recently edited [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/which-martial-art-uses-knee-on-neck-to-subdue-an-opponent) on MA stack exchange, and within 10 minutes posted an answer. My answer received 2 votes.

When I look at my badges, the "explainer" badge has not yet been conquered. Now, this is where it get's strange:
[image]

Notice that I have 1/500 for "Illuminator", which means that I should have gotten the "explainer" badge already. Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: How long has it been? All badges are cached to some degree.

Comment: @Catija Both actions were about 5-6 hours ago, but I had the same problem a few months ago and it never got fixed.

Comment: The last one awarded here on MSE took almost 24 hours to be awarded from the timestamp of the edit. The one prior to that took about 30 hours. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer

Comment: @Catija As far as I'm aware, badge trackers are loaded live, and aren't cached unlike the actual badge award script. I've seen some cases where the badge tracker says "Congratulations - you've earned [badge]" when I qualify for a badge but it hasn't been awarded to me yet. Does that only happen on badges that track progress?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Until we're out of the caching window for this... I'm ... not really sure that matters in this case. The badge is clearly still being awarded in general so there's not a general bug and there's no way to know there even is a bug here until the badge is awarded. The long caching period could even be intentional for this version of the badge to prevent people from submitting edits just to get the badge - if the edit gets rolled back within that window, they wouldn't get it.

Comment: @Catija Are you suggesting I wait a few days and then report back? What should I do?

Comment: Give it some time. If you still don't have it this time tomorrow, let me know. Otherwise, feel free to self answer saying that it just took forever.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274610/explainer-badge-not-awarded Dupe - Also worth noting, you didn't get any votes until three hours ago, so the timer for being awarded starts once the score is above 0. I forgot to look at the timeline to see when the MSE answers got upvotes, too... so that likely explains the delay in those cases.

Comment: [Explainer](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/badges/90/explainer) was awarded on MA.se 20 times, last time May 31 '19. That's not as often as I'd expect on a site that old. But for this specific question, I'd wait another couple of hours and see what happens. Caching does strange things at times on SE.

Comment: The badge [has been awarded](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/badges/90/explainer?userid=10555), so this seems to not be a bug.