# Diamond’s background height is more than for initial part of the name in iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, moderators

When the topic starter is a mod, and he have post a comment then  the text background height for the diamond is slightly more in the iOS app. E.g. [Tim Post’s comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator#comment785922_239898):

> [image: ios]

In the web version background height is same for whole name:

> [image: web]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.2.1 (Build 15C153)

Comment: Diamonds can simply not be compressed in the same way as humans for mobile use ;)