# Query for no. of many questions I have answered which are closed later

Tags: support, search, data-explorer, closed-questions

Is there a query to know how many questions received answers before they are put on hold and *I am one of the users who wrote an answer* before the question is closed?

If it looks confusing, let me explain. For example, you write an answer for a question. Later, the question gets closed as duplicate or too broad or any other reason. Take a look at this question

[Time for some more swag!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910/357396)

It was open for a limited period of time but closed later. It received 129 answers in the mean time. Similarly, if I want to find such questions which were open when I wrote an answer and later closed, is there a Data Explorer query? I have gone through [search operators in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) and tried [`closed:yes is:a user:me`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+closed%3Ayes+user%3Ame) but it returns closed questions asked by me. Is there a tip I am missing?

Is there a query for returning intended input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is similar query to the other answer, but it also includes the questions which were closed and later reopened (not only the one which are still closed).

[Questions answered by a user before they were closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/1092486/1348915/questions-answered-by-a-user-before-they-were-closed?UserId=357396)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Id AS [Post Link]
  FROM PostHistory AS ph
  INNER JOIN Posts AS a
    ON a.ParentId = ph.PostId
   AND a.CreationDate < ph.CreationDate 
   AND ph.PostHistoryTypeId=10
  WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
ORDER BY a.Id ASC
```

This does not include deleted posts - SEDE stores only some information on deleted posts (in the PostsWithDeleted table), author of the post is not among them.

Answer (score 6):

[Yes, there is now](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1092749/questions-answered-by-a-user-before-they-were-closed?UserId=357396).

I've got five answers by you on Meta Stack Exchange which qualify:

[image]

The query looks at questions which are *currently* closed; if they have been reopened in the meantime, they will not appear in the results.

After a request by Sonic, the query now also tells you if the answer would have qualified for the Explainer / Refiner / Illuminator badge, or why not: [answers on closed questions don't count for those badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/295232).

Comment: Can you please add another column for whether the answer would qualify for the Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator badge series had the question been open? (If the question later gets closed at any point, the answer ceases to qualify.)

Comment: I never realized that; the query has now been updated.