# Do edit rollbacks affect explainer/refiner/illuminator badge progress?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks, edit-and-answer-badges

I answered a question, was upvoted, and then edited the question. My badge progress was immediately updated.

Then I thought better of my edit and rolled it back. My badge progress remained incremented.

1. Just confirming this is the expected behavior, as opposed to my badge progress being decremented.
2. Would the behavior be different if someone else had rolled back my edit?

Comment: To answer your first two questions: no, your edit being later rolled back will not decrement your progress, whether it's done by you or anyone else. The only cases where the counter is decremented is if your answer's score drops below 1 or if the question is later closed.

Comment: I've edited that information into the badge criteria FAQ. I don't know the answer to the third one, though I suspect it doesn't since rollbacks are treated differently from edits in the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer →Refiner → Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239941/282094):   `"I don't think additional quality controls for the edits are necessary here. In fact, I don't think we even need to take rollbacks into account - if your edit was approved / applied, and the question it was applied to stays open (and visible - deleted questions shouldn't count either!), then it counts."`.

Comment: @Rob Although that Q&A provides discussion, it doesn't provide a definitive answer. However, in light of Sonic's edits to the [badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for), I've voted to close my question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: It doesn't answer question 3 however. I'd instead edit your question so that that's the only question it asks.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm actually going to open #3 as a separate question. I think there's value in leaving #1 and #2 should someone else have the same questions. It'll make the answer easier to find.

Comment: @Aaron my suggested duplicate does indeed claim to answer all three, but marking the FAQ as the duplicate is fair; and on MSE it's allowed even if there's no answer, always seems *kinder* if there is one. In any event the additional link appears in the right column, which is also helpful.